# MYSQL Sum and Count on different tables, in same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, sum

Im trying to get some stats; total links, users and views, from 3 different tables.
What im trying:

```
SELECT SUM(p.views), COUNT(c.id), COUNT(u.id)
FROM studenkel_userprefs as p, studenkel_content as c, studenkel_users as u
```

If I do them individually in three different queries, they work fine, but togheter the results gets a couple thousand times higher than what i want. I guess they multiply eachother in some way, Tips?

Thanks

Edit: Thanks guys, really appreciate your help, sorted it out.

Comment: When you list the tables this way `FROM studenkel_userprefs as p, studenkel_content as c, studenkel_users as u` it will give you a Cartesian product for all the rows from the three tables, it is also called `CROSS JOIN` you should use `INNER JOIN` but you need to specify how the three tables relate to each other, please update your question and show how they are related.

Comment: That query will result in a cartesian join, you need to join your tables together.

Comment: use a proper `JOIN` syntax, and tell the DB **HOW** those tables relate to each other, e.g. in this exact case you need a where clause: `... WHERE studenkel_userprefs.foo = studenkel_content.bar AND etc...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing in your from is called implicit inner joins without criteria.

Which means your final view have `p.rows * c.rows * u.rows` rows and that's why you have weird result.

If you have 3 questions, ask them separately, not all at once.

Alternatively, if you really want only one request, you could go with something ugly as :

```
SELECT
  SELECT SUM(views) FROM studenkel_userprefs as "sum_userprefs",
  SELECT COUNT(id) FROM studenkel_content as "cnt_content",
  SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM studenkel_users as "cnt_users"
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to "cheat"?

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(p.views)
        FROM 
            studenkel_userprefs as p
    ) as `views`,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(c.id)
        FROM
            studenkel_content as c
    ) as `content_count`,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(u.id)
        FROM
            studenkel_users as u
    ) as `user_count`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are making a Cartesian join of the tables, which multiplies the number of rows in one table times the number of rows in each other table.  Without specifying a join in either `JOIN ... ON` format or by specifying the join criteria in `WHERE` clause, this is the only result you will get.